# On showing that a given set is an Algebra

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble on showing this:

$\bullet$)We say a set $A$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is a periodic set if exists an integer $i$ and a set $I$ $\subset$ $\{1,\cdots,i\}$ such that:
$$A = \bigcup_{l=-\infty}^{\infty}(I+li)$$
where $I+li=\{n+li:n\in I \}$. Show that
$$\mathcal{F}=\{A\subset\mathbb{Z}:A \text{ is a periodic set}\}$$
is an algebra on $\mathbb{Z}$

I know I need to check three propierties:

1) $\mathbb{Z} \in \mathcal{F}$

2) if $A\in\mathcal{F}$ then $A^{c}\in \mathcal{F}$

3) if $A_{1},\cdots ,A_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k} \in \mathcal{F}$

But... How can I start arguing? I'm new at this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm trying to work out exactly how the last property holds. But for the first one, try $i=1$.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set $i=1$. Actually, any $i$ would do provided $I=\{1,...,i\}$.

2) Consider sets of the form $\{n+li : n\in \{1,...,i\}-I \}$

3) Since your union is finite, it suffices to show that $A_1,A_2\in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow A_1\cup A_2 \in \mathcal{F}$.

Let $A_1=\bigcup_{l\in \mathbb{Z}}(I+li)$ and $A_2 = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} (J+kj)$.  Show in particular that $A_1 \cup A_2 = \bigcup_{l\in \mathbb{Z}}((I\cup J)+lij)$